# setup ClearCanvas Library to use in C#

Tags: c#, installation, dicom, clearcanvas

i want to use clearcanvas library in C# for DICOM image Viewer. I have searched much but Unfortunately i did not found how to setup this library to be used with my project in C#.
There is no information of using this library with my project in VS 2010 even at the website of ClearCanvas..  please help me in this regard ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn all about that in the [ClearCanvas Developer's Guide](http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/Portals/0/ClearCanvasFiles/Documentation/DevelopersGuide/2_0_SP1/).